# Sharing my dashboard/workbook with others without sharing my data in Tableau Online/Public?

Tags: tableau-api

I have purchased Tableau Online to share my workbooks with a specific group of people without providing an option to download the actual data I used to create them. But I figured that other users would also need a license to view/edit my workbooks..

My initial plan was to share my published workbooks and put them on my website so that others (that I specify) can VIEW the workbook without offering them a privilege of downloading the data. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Your requirement cannot be achieved without use of Tableau Server, or purchasing additional licenses for the specific group of users. :(

Answer (score 1):

When you publish your workbook to online specify permissions so that users
- cannot download the workbook
- cannot edit the workbook
- cannot view the underlying data

If you give your audience accounts with only viewing permission and you have those restricted permissions for workbooks, then you can simply send your audience links and they will see the visualizations in their browser without having to download workbooks. Even if they did download the workbooks, their accounts would be prevented from looking any deeper into the data than your workbooks show.

Comment: I guess you are referring to Tableau Online. Regardless of specifying permissions, don't the users still need a licence to view my workbook? If not, could you elaborate a bit more as to where I could set the permissions? When I published my workbook online, I have retrieved the following URL, but again, the problem is that no one is able to see without a licence as they are automatically redirected to "singin" page... https://10ay.online.tableau.com/t/itsslab/views/iWinMan-SaltManagement/Dashboard-LOS?:embed=y&:retry=yes&:display_count=no

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Tableau JavaScript API. Once you have your workbooks hosted with Tableau Online you can display them using the API on your own website. Then just share the link to those you want to have viewing rights.

This will be public to whoever has the link though unless you set the location up to require login.

http://www.tableau.com/new-features/javascript-api

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts datalove. But I believe the "Download" will still appear at the bottom right corner, giving the option of downloading the actual data I used... I am not sure if it is even possible to remove the option, but that will be ideal..

Comment: My bad. I thought you could disable that if not using Tableau Public. Here is a reference to deny data access to the workbook at the user level. I will still look around for a solution through the API though. http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/help.htm#datasource_perm_set.htm

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I think you are now referring to Tableau Server which I don't have a licence for. Even if I purchase it, I have a feeling that it will require every user to have their own licence even to view my workbooks.. I guess the API is the way to go...

Comment: Try this. When you click on the link to share, use the display options dropdown and disable the toolbar. http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/shareworkbooks.htm

Answer (score 1):

http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/windows/en-us/publish_workbooks_howto.html

http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/windows/en-us/Img/publish9.png

When you see this window, click on a User/group, and click Edit. Tableau has default roles (Viewer, Interactor, etc.). You can modify the Interactor role so that it becomes a Custom role so that someone can't download your workbook, etc.

http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/publish_workbooks_permissions_add.html

See here for more details on permissions.

Comment: Thanks John for your reply. Do I need to purchase a license for Tableau Sever? I do have a Tableau Online and I played around with setting permissions, but regardless, the people I shared my published workbooks with were not able to see simply because they don't have a license to view.

Comment: No, we just have Tableau Online. No need for Server unless you want to do Windows Authentication and other cool stuff. You can't just email someone a link, add them as a user first. http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/sites_addusers.htm http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/users_site_roles.htm we have most of our users as a variation of  "Interactor". Since Tableau doesn't allow permanent custom roles, we have to constantly create a custom role for every user/workbook...

Comment: Thanks John... I am aware of this. Like I said, I have only one licence and do not have any licence available for another person to view my workbook (Available quota: 0)..

Comment: You would need additional licenses ($500 per user). How are your data sources structured? Online? Or local extracts? Maybe you should just forgo Online, use local extracts, and publish twbx files, and have your people install Tableau Reader.